# Mock html-webpack-plugin's getHooks static method with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to mock the [getHooks](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/318cd4d1d3158c24a2f0cb3e900989701d4c4d9c/index.js#L1205C1-L1205C56) static method on the HtmlWebpackPlugin class provided by the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) library.

I have a Webpack plugin (ES6) that I need to test that looks like this:

```
import { Compiler, Compilation } from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

export class MyPlugin {
    public apply(compiler: Compiler): void {
        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
            'MyPlugin',
            (compilation: Compilation) => {
                HtmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks(compilation).beforeEmit.tapAsync(
                    'MyPlugin',
                    (data, cb) => {
                        // Work with data...
                        cb(null, data);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried using jest.mock (ES6 module mock) at the top of the test file, creating a spyOn on the getHooks method, overwriting the method with a mock function...  I can't seem to get the implementation being called within my method under test to use a mock.

Perhaps I'm missing something in translation between CommonJs and ES6?  At least I believe the library in Cjs:

```
class HtmlWebpackPlugin { /* detail removed */ }

HtmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks = getHtmlWebpackPluginHooks;

module.exports = HtmlWebpackPlugin;
```

My plugin works fine, I just can't seem to test it.